# Aria Expanded Menu Responsive

Tags: jquery, events

I have a responsive menu and wanna expand/collapse by a condition and my question are double:

1. Can I get the event when menu attribute change? f.e.: the attr is **aria-expanded**, ok, so have a function as `$('#ID').on('aria-expanded-changed')`
2. Can I change position of menu by css? When make click on button to expand it, the menu appears on top and the logo image is on top. Can I change position and put it at bottom of logo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem with events jQuery. First, when you make click in button to expand the menu, check if the nav is expanded or not; if it's false, move the menu X pixels to bottom and otherwhise margin = 0 px

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var expanded = $('#nav_sup').attr('aria-expanded');
    (expanded == 'false') ? $('#ul_nav').css('margin-top', '120px') : $('#ul_nav').css('margin-top', '0px');
});
```

And another point to take is when the size of the windows is resized, make the reset of the options:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $('#nav_sup').removeClass('in');
    $('#nav_sup').attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
    $('#ul_nav').css('margin-top', '0px');
});
```

By the moment, works...